# Button inside Custom Annotation won't react

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I've designed a custom annotation, an the view looks just fine. But there's a button inside the view, an when Im tap it, nothings happen. It should print something in the log to begin with.
Here's my codes from the Custom Annotation class.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import CoreData


class CustomAnnotation: MKPinAnnotationView, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let firmaLabel : UILabel = UILabel.init(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: -50, width: 200, height: 50))
let infoButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)


override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(true, animated: animated)


        firmaLabel.textAlignment = .center
        firmaLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        firmaLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "Trebuchet MS", size: 20)
        firmaLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        firmaLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        firmaLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        firmaLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true

        infoButton.frame = CGRect(x: -50, y: -50, width: 50, height: 50)
        infoButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        infoButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        infoButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        infoButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        infoButton.setTitle(">", for: UIControlState.normal)

//The code below is the way I imagine it should make it work??

        infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        firmaLabel.text = "Hello"
        self.addSubview(firmaLabel)

        self.addSubview(infoButton)

}

func btnClicked (_: UIButton) {
    print("Hello world")
  }
}
```

This is how it looks when I run the project. It looks just as it should

[image]

Im calling the custom annotation inside the Viewcontroller this way

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation
    {
        return nil
    }
    var annotationView = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "Pin")
    if annotationView == nil{
        annotationView = CustomAnnotation(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Pin")
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = false
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: it is print the log or not

Comment: Not sure about what you mean

Comment: the button action is caled or not

Comment: So why won't it work? It won't print anything when I tap it

Comment: add the breakpoint and check once its called or not

Comment: If you double tap on the button, does your map zoom?

Comment: Yes the map zooms when I double tap on the button

Comment: I just disabled the zoom, but the button still won't react @Magnas

Comment: Yes, sorry, had to go out. Was just wondering if the map was stealing all the touches and if maybe setting cancelsTouchesInView was appropriate. I'm guessing  isUserInteractionEnabled is on by default for UIButtons created programmatically.

Comment: Yes, userInteractionEnable is on. Can't figure out why it won't react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are creating a MKPinAnnotation view, and adding two extra views onto that. You should use a callout view for that. In your existing code, mouse clicks will only 'go through' on the pin, try moving the button down so it covers the pin, and you see the selector (that need to be updated) will get called.

If you just want to show a button quick, consider adding it as a callout accessory view like this (in your ViewCtrl):

```
if annotationView == nil{
        annotationView = CustomAnnotation(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "Pin") //Might as well be MKPinAnnotationView
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

        let infoButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

        infoButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        infoButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        infoButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        infoButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        infoButton.layer.masksToBounds = true

        infoButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton

    }
```

And then remember to add the action:

```
    func buttonClicked() {
    print("Button Clicked")
}
```

Result:

[image]

Edit: Take a look at Apples "MapCallouts" example code, they show different kinds of annotations for both iOS and macOS. Very usefull!

Comment: Okay, thanks. I see what you mean. But its just not only a detail button I want to make. It should be a view with labels and image in it. I don't think its possible to design the callout, inside the viewForAnnotation?

Comment: No, don't try to do that. Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html for examples on how to create your own custom callout views.